# caollada modell from aframe do not appear when uploaded to server

Tags: aframe, collada

I using aframe collada-model with localhost which works, when uploaded to net no models appear.  Images appear OK from their subdirectory.

```
<a-collada-model
id = "passover"
position ="0 -1.5 3"
rotation = "0 0 0"
scale = "4 4 4"
src = "models/Passover.dae"
>
</a-collada-model>
```